# Name for metric spaces with useful unique-ball-intersection property?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology

When dealing with the problem of extending a Lipschitz function $f:A \to Y$ between metric spaces across an inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$, one often imposes (conditions which imply) the following property on the target space $Y$. I'd like to know if this property has a name.

Let me describe our property: there exists a uniform bound $d \in (0,\infty)$ so that the following holds. Given (**a**) any finite subset $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\} \subset Y$ of diameter smaller than $d$, and (**b**) any sequence $\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$ of strictly positive real numbers, define 
$$I(t) = \bigcap_1^n \text{Ball}(\text{center}=y_i,\text{radius}=r_it) $$ and let $\bar{t}$ be the infimum over all $t \geq 0$ so that $I(t) \neq \varnothing$. Then, our property says that the set $I(\bar{t})$ contains a unique element $y \in Y$.

See for instance the crucial Prop 4.2 in Lang/Schroeder's amazing 1997 GAFA paper [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/lang-schroeder_kirszbraun.pdf), which shows that every complete $Cat(k)$ space satisfies something stronger.

---

For what it's worth, I've been sorely tempted to call such metric spaces "Hellyscapes" after [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), so you'll probably be doing the entire community a service by talking me out of it...